# copy Function constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype

I'd like to substitute the Function constructor for fn so that

```
function hello(){ console.log("hello") }
```

will give the same result as

```
fn lazyHi(){ console.log("I'm a lazy function!") }
```

I'm interested mainly to test my own understanding of JavaScript inheritance patterns, but I'm not sure this can be done at the "root" level.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use "fn" in  place of the function keyword. If so, no, you cannot do that.

Comment: But the second will always be a syntax error

Comment: You would need `fn` to be an operator or special keyword. But you can't define new operators.

Comment: got it. should I have known that? why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace the "function" keyword with your own "fn" keyword. That would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it. That is if you wrote your own compile to JavaScript tool like coffee script and the like.